# puppet librarian Could not resolve the dependencies

Tags: puppet, librarian-puppet

I have a problem with puppet librarian resolving dependencies. When I run `librarian-puppet install --verbose` for this `Puppetfile`:

```rb
forge "https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com"

mod "puppetlabs-java"
mod "puppetlabs-stdlib"
mod "puppetlabs-mysql"

mod "camptocamp/tomcat","0.8.7"
mod "xebialabs-xldeploy","1.2.3"
```

I get a error resolving dependencies. I don't know what is wrong.
Any help please?

```html
root@tomcat1:/etc/puppet# librarian-puppet install --verbose
[Librarian] Ruby Version: 2.5.1
[Librarian] Ruby Platform: x86_64-linux-gnu
[Librarian] Rubygems Version: 2.7.6
[Librarian] Librarian Version: 0.6.4
[Librarian] Librarian Adapter: puppet
[Librarian] Librarian Adapter Version: 3.0.0
[Librarian] Project: /etc/puppet
[Librarian] Specfile: Puppetfile
[Librarian] Lockfile: Puppetfile.lock
[Librarian] Git: /usr/bin/git
[Librarian] Git Version: 2.17.1
[Librarian] Git Environment Variables:
[Librarian]   (empty)
[Librarian] Pre-Cached Sources:
[Librarian]   [:forge, "https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com", {}]
[Librarian] Post-Cached Sources:
[Librarian]   [:forge, "https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com", {}]
[Librarian] Analyzing spec and lock:
[Librarian]   Removed:
[Librarian]   ExplicitRemoved:
[Librarian]   Added:
[Librarian]   NonMatchingAdded:
[Librarian]   Changed:
[Librarian]     camptocamp-tomcat
[Librarian]   DeepKeep:
[Librarian]     puppetlabs-java
[Librarian]     puppetlabs-mysql
[Librarian]     puppetlabs-stdlib
[Librarian]     xebialabs-xldeploy
[Librarian]   ShallowStrip:
[Librarian]     camptocamp-tomcat
[Librarian] Resolving camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]   Checking manifests
[Librarian]   Module camptocamp-tomcat found versions: 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.17.1, 0.17.0, 0.16.5, 0.16.3, 0.16.2, 0.16.1, 0.15.0, 0.14.2, 0.14.1, 0.14.0, 0.13.9, 0.13.8, 0.13.6, 0.13.5, 0.13.4, 0.13.3, 0.13.2, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.12.0, 0.11.2, 0.11.0, 0.10.5, 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.0, 0.8.10, 0.8.9, 0.8.8, 0.8.7, 0.8.6, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.4, 0.7.3, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.0, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/1.2.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/1.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/1.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/1.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/1.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/1.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/1.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.17.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.17.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.17.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.17.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.17.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.17.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.16.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.15.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.15.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.15.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.14.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.9 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.9 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.9 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.8 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.8 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.8 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.6 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.6 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.6 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.13.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.12.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.12.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.12.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.11.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.11.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.11.2 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.11.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.11.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.11.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.5 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.3 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.10.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.9.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.9.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.9.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.10 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.10 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.10 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.9 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.9 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.9 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.8 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.8 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.8 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.7 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Resolved camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> at camptocamp-tomcat/0.8.7 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]   Resolved camptocamp-tomcat (= 0.8.7) <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian] Resolving camptocamp-archive (< 2.0.0, >= 0.3.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]   Checking manifests
[Librarian]   Module camptocamp-archive found versions: 0.9.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.5, 0.7.4, 0.7.3, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.6, 0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1, 0.1.0, 0.0.1
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-archive/0.9.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Resolved camptocamp-archive (< 2.0.0, >= 0.3.0) <(no source specified)> at camptocamp-archive/0.9.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]   Resolved camptocamp-archive (< 2.0.0, >= 0.3.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian] Resolving camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]   Checking manifests
[Librarian]   Module camptocamp-systemd found versions: 2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.4.0, 0.3.0, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.15, 0.1.14, 0.1.13, 0.1.12, 0.1.11, 0.1.10, 0.1.9, 0.1.8, 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.8.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.8.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.8.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.7.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.7.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.7.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.6.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.6.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.6.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.5.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.5.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.5.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.4.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.4.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.4.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.3.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.3.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.3.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.2.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.2.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.2.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/2.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between camptocamp-systemd/2.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from camptocamp-systemd/2.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking camptocamp-systemd/1.1.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Resolved camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)> at camptocamp-systemd/1.1.1 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]   Resolved camptocamp-systemd (< 2.0.0, >= 0.1.5) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian] Resolving herculesteam-augeasproviders_core (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]   Checking manifests
[Librarian]   Module herculesteam-augeasproviders_core found versions: 2.5.0, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.5, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.0
[Librarian]     Checking herculesteam-augeasproviders_core/2.5.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Resolved herculesteam-augeasproviders_core (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)> at herculesteam-augeasproviders_core/2.5.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]   Resolved herculesteam-augeasproviders_core (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian] Resolving herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]   Checking manifests
[Librarian]   Module herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar found versions: 4.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.0.0, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.4, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0
[Librarian]     Checking herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/4.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/4.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/4.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/3.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/3.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/3.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/3.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Conflict between herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/3.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com> and herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian]       Backtracking from herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/3.0.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]     Checking herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/2.2.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]       Resolved herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)> at herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar/2.2.4 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
[Librarian]   Resolved herculesteam-augeasproviders_shellvar (< 3.0.0, >= 2.0.0) <(no source specified)>
[Librarian] Conflict between puppetlabs-inifile (< 2.0.0, >= 1.0.0) <(no source specified)> and puppetlabs-inifile/4.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
Could not resolve the dependencies.
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/action/persist_resolution_mixin.rb:11:in `persist_resolution'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:32:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarian-puppet-3.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/action/resolve.rb:10:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarian-puppet-3.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/cli.rb:104:in `resolve!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarian-puppet-3.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/cli.rb:68:in `install'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in bin!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/cli.rb:31:in `returning_status'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `block in bin!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/cli.rb:47:in `with_environment'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarianp-0.6.4/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `bin!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/librarian-puppet-3.0.0/bin/librarian-puppet:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/librarian-puppet:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/librarian-puppet:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the last error, the problems appears to be that there is a conflict between required versions of `inifile`.

```
Conflict between puppetlabs-inifile (< 2.0.0, >= 1.0.0) <(no source specified)> and puppetlabs-inifile/4.1.0 <https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com>
```

Try adding

```
  mod 'puppetlabs-inifile', '1.6.0'
```

to the `Puppetfile`.

Also, I'd note that there is another conflict you'll come across with `stdlib`. Add

```
  mod "puppetlabs-stdlib", "4.25.1"
```

to fix it.

Also, I'd strongly suggest pinning the versions of the `java` and `mysql` modules. If you don't do that, you can't guarantee you won't have more conflicts at some point in the future.